# Mobile phone client not connecting to local Python server

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, backend

So, I created this http server in Python that shares any folder on my PC so i could access it with my phone.
I tried connecting and kept getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on all mobile browsers on my phone.
Funnily enough, Visual Studio's Live Server extension does this perfectly
Here's the code:

```
# Chicken Server v1.0 by Rene Geni
import webbrowser as wb
from tkinter import *
import http.server
import socketserver
import webbrowser as wb
import random
import os

# Define the IP address and port for the server
ip = "localhost"
port = 9000

# Create a custom request handler that disables caching


class NoCacheRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header(
            'Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0')
        self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
        super().end_headers()
# Function to start the server


def start_server():
    server_path = os.chdir(text_field.get())
    with socketserver.TCPServer((ip, port), NoCacheRequestHandler) as httpd:
        print(f'Serving directory "{server_path}" at http://{ip}:{port}')
        wb.open(f"http://{ip}:{port}")
        try:
            httpd.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass


# GUI logic
window = Tk()
window.title("Chicken Server")
greeting = Label(text="Enter directory path")
text_field = Entry(width="30")
# Bind the button to the start_server function
submit = Button(text="Start server", command=start_server)
message = Label(text="To close the server, just close the window")
greeting.pack()
text_field.pack()
submit.pack()
message.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I was expecting the directory to be visible on my mobile browser,
and I tried adding read permissions with chmod on Linux,
but it still didn't work

Comment: Have you checked if your router ports are open for the port you are setting up?

Comment: I thought that `localhost` couldn't be accessed from the outside.

Comment: It depends on how you are exposing (binding) it I guess, if you need it exposed throughout your entire network, you will prolly need to add "0.0.0.0" as the ip and to access it from your mobile, you will have to type in the ip address of your system with your port but again, you wont be able to access it outside your network.

Comment: Do I use something like Nmap to scan for open ports

Comment: Also, localhost can be accessed from outside with the IP address of the device acting as the server